Thorx6 - Engraving machine (Convert Font TTF to SLF)
I have an engraving machine that uses the Thorx6 program, which supports TTF or SLF files. However, the font I need isn't in either of these formats. I need to convert it to .SLF or create a new one directly in this format. Does anyone know of any tools or software that can help with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I found a TTF font, i saw a preview and its what i want, but when i put import to the software, it turns another font, like this:
Name of font: OCR-A BT
Example:
Font tipe TTF
When i import to the software:
Software font
I'm expecting a name of a software where i can convert it (TTF to SLF)
Or how can i create from the start a SLF font
